# lua (Roblox) - Help needed with cloning a tool into the players backpack

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

so I am making a game with a shop and the problem I am having is that I have a tool in ReplicatedStorage so I can clone it into the players backpack when the player buys that tool. The problem is that wherever I put the tool it disappears. I have tried ServerStorage, ReplicatedStorage, Workspace and inside the script but everytime I test the game it removes it from anywhere I put it. I will put my script below but I don't know if that is broken yet, I haven't been able to test it because the tool gets removed from anywhere I put it. Here is my code in a LocalScript in a TextButton in StarterGUI.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local tool = script.Tool:Clone()
    tool.Parent = player.Backpack
    print("player recieved tool")
end)
```

and that gets triggered from a Touched event in script in a part in Workspace.

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        print(hit.Parent)
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Shop:Fire(player)
    end
end)
```

So, Those might work but I only need help with the actual tool vanishing. Any help appreciated! (If you want images or videos I can record them and send a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as the problem might be that the server doesn't know you got the item since it's all done on the localside. Try using something like a RemoteEvent.

Localside:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local RemoteEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    RemoteEvent:FireServer()
end)
```

You'll need to add a RemoteEvent to ReplicatedStorage.
Server side:

```
local RemoteEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent
local ToolPrefab = --add the directory of the weapon here
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    local ToolClone = ToolPrefab:Clone()
    ToolClone.Parent = plr.Back
end)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help. I didn't think I would have to do anything server side.